# Is there a better way to create Class than this?

Tags: c#

I have lots of class who inherit abstract class and many interface.
but problem is class should implement members declared in interface.
so I should type lots of duplicate code.

I think that violates OOP's DRY principle, So I tried many things but below is my best.

Is there any way better than mine?

Current

```
public interface InterfaceWithProperties
{
    public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass1 
{
    public abstract Guid GuidProperty1;
}

public abstract class AbstractClass2
{
    public abstract Guid GuidProperty2;
}

public sealed class DerivativeClass1 : AbstractClass1, InterfaceWithProperties
{
    [TargetAttribute(ValueForDerivativeClass1)] public override Guid GuidProperty1 { get; set; }

    [SomeAttribute] public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    [SomeAttribute] public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DerivativeClass2 : AbstractClass2, InterfaceWithProperties
{
    [TargetAttribute(ValueForDerivativeClass2)] public override GuidProperty2 { get; set; }

    [SomeAttribute] public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    [SomeAttribute] public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

There could be a lot of sealed derivative class with different base class but same interface.
so below parts duplicate many times

```
{
    [SomeAttribute] public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    [SomeAttribute] public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

So Is There a way to declare this part of code for my purpose?

for example I imagine some "augmentation" type achieve like this.

```
public augmentation AugmentationWithProperties : InterfaceWithProperties
{
    [SomeAttribute] public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
    [SomeAttribute] public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

so now derivative classes look like these

```
public sealed class DerivativeClass1 : AbstractClass1, AugmentationWithProperties
{
    [TargetAttribute(ValueForDerivativeClass1)] public override Guid GuidProperty1 { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DerivativeClass2 : AbstractClass2, AugmentationWithProperties
{
    [TargetAttribute(ValueForDerivativeClass2)] public override Guid GuidProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Is There a Way to achieve this?

Please Give me your advice, Thank you.

Comment: **You code doesn't compile**.  You cannot have `abstract` fields. (`public abstract Guid GuidProperty1;`)

Comment: What do GuidProperty1 and GuidProperty2 signify? Do they represent something like id? Perhaps they could be called Id in that case (i.e. one property). What is TargetAttribute's purpose here?

Comment: Each class have their own Identity, and by TargetAttribute Classes are linked. Finally, they make a big data tree

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here. The problem is too abstract because it lacks detail.